# Python - The request headers for mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize

I am looking for a way to view the request (not response) headers, specifically what browser mechanize claims to be. Also how would I go about manipulating them, eg setting another browser?

Example:

```
import mechanize
browser = mechanize.Browser()
# Now I want to make a request to eg example.com with custom headers using browser
```

The purpose is of course to test a website and see whether or not it shows different pages depending on the reported browser.

It has to be the mechanize browser as the rest of the code depends on it (but is left out as it's irrelevant.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
browser.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 blahblah')]
```

Comment: I can live without knowing what headers mechanize use default for now. Answer accepted!

Answer (score 2):

You've got an answer on how to change the headers, but if you want to see the exact headers that are being used try using a proxy that displays the traffic. e.g. Fiddler2 on windows or see [this question for some Linux altenatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040642/linux-alternative-to-fiddler2).

Comment: this is a good site to view your headers: http://www.ericgiguere.com/tools/http-header-viewer.html

Answer (score 2):

you can modify referer too...

```
br.addheaders = [('Referer', 'http://google.com')]
```